# C++ Char array not working

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get this program working, but get odd output. I know a char buffer is not ideal here, but it's for an assignment and not of my own design. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;


//Place your class definition here
class student {
   public:
      void inputData(int a, char s[20], float e, float m, float sci);
      void printData();

   private:
      int admno;
      char sname[20];
      float eng;
      float math;
      float science;
      float total;
      float ctotal();
};


int main ()   //This is your main driver.  Do NOT make any changes to it
{
    student obj ;
    int a;
    char s[20];
    float e, m, sci;
    cin >> a;
    cin.getline(s,20);
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(10,'\n');
    cin >> e;
    cin >> m;
    cin >> sci;
    obj.inputData(a, s, e, m, sci);
    obj.printData();
    return 0;
}

//Place your class member function definitions here

void student::inputData(int a, char s[], float e, float m, float sci) {
   admno = a;
   *sname = *s;
   eng = e;
   math = m;
   science = sci;
   total = ctotal();
}

void student::printData() {
   cout << "Admission number: " << admno << endl << "Student name: ";
   for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
      cout << sname[i];
   cout << endl << "English: " << eng << endl << "Math: " << science << endl << "Science: " << science << endl << "Total: " << total;
}

float student::ctotal() {
   return (eng + math + science);
}
```

Here's my input:

```
98745
Kyle Smith
98
78
62
```

Here's the expected output:

```
Admission number: 98745
Student name: Kyle Smith
English: 98
Math: 78
Science: 62
Total: 238
```

Here's the actual output:

```
Admission number: 98745
Student name:   m  ╩`uÄM■Å■   ║k`u
English: 98
Math: 62
Science: 62
Total: 238
```

Please give advice on how to fix. I have to stick with that char buffer, but don't know why I'm getting this corruption.
Thanks!

Comment: Step through with a debugger and watch for where the program differs from what you expect.

Comment: Simplify your life, use `std::string` for text, not character arrays.  Character arrays can suffer from overrun.  Also, if the array doesn't have the nul terminator, many algorithms keep going into other parts of memory until the nul is found.

Answer (score 2):

```
*sname = *s;
```

This copies one character, not the entire string.  If you want to copy the entire string, you need to use [`std::strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy)

```
std::strcpy(sname, s);
```

or a loop

```
char* src = s;
char* dst = sname;
while (src) {
    *dst = *src;
    ++src;
    ++dst;
}
```

Of course, you could do away with all of this manual string handling and use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead:

```
//Place your class definition here
class student {
   public:
      void inputData(int a, std::string s, float e, float m, float sci);
      void printData();

   private:
      int admno;
      std::string sname;
      float eng;
      float math;
      float science;
      float total;
      float ctotal();
};

void student::inputData(int a, std::string s, float e, float m, float sci) {
   admno = a;
   sname = std::move(s);
   eng = e;
   math = m;
   science = sci;
   total = ctotal();
}
```

Comment: `This copies one character` Then at least 1st char should show in the output, but this is not the case

Answer (score 1):

Here is what happening:

```
cin >> a;
cin.getline(s,20);
cin.clear(); // never mind this, doesn't do anything in this context
cin.ignore(10,'\n');
```

1. Your `int` is read and stored in `a`
2. `cin` now contains `\n` left over after you pressed `Enter`
3. `getline` immediately attempts to read it into `s` but it discards it, `s` is now empty, but `getline` operation is complete.
4. Why does it still wait for the input of the name? Because `cin.ignore` is waiting for `\n` or at least 10 `char`s to be entered, but the stream buffer is now empty.
5. You enter your name and press `Enter`, `ignore` at least gets its `\n` and is now complete but your entered string is not stored anywhere. It is just ignored. If it wasn't ignored you would have gotten the 1st `char` of this string in the output, but you haven't.

Long story short, your input is broken. You should clear that `\n` after you entered the first number before `getline`. Only then, after you have your name stored in `s` you can attempt to pass it to the function, there is no point in passing a pointer to empty array and expecting it to work.